# Google Sheets/Excel: Counting values in a range that changes with each row, across multiple rows?

Tags: arrays, excel, count, google-sheets, instance

```
       A            B              C             D             E
 +--------------------------------------------------------------
1| Red          Blue           Dark Green    Blue
2| Light Blue   Red            Blue          Red
3| Blue         Black          Dark Green
4| Light Blue   Light Blue
5| Dark Green
6| Blue         Red            Green         Black         Blue
7| Dark Green   Blue
```

So what I'm trying to accomplish is to count how many times a value (say, 'Blue') appears between the First and Last cells that contain any value in a set of rows.

Using the above example the result should be '2' for 'Blue', where by 'Blue' can be found '6' times across the whole range, but I want to exclude all instances that appear in the first and last positions of any given row.

I wish I had an example of the formula I've been using so far, but I haven't been able to produce anything that works properly. :(

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$D$5="Blue")*NOT(COLUMN($A$1:$D$5)=1)*NOT($B$1:$E$5=""))`

Three parts in the `SUMPRODUCT`

1. `($A$1:$D$5="Blue")` Checks the values of each cells whether they match the target or not.
2. `NOT(COLUMN($A$1:$D$5)=1)` The cell should not be in column #1. However this can be omitted if you use the range B1:D5.
3. `NOT($B$1:$E$5="")` If the cell is the last one of that row, the next cell would be a blank. Therefore we check the following cells are blank or not.

Comment: Looks good, but I think OP wants to exclude the first column, not the first row, and the last one in each row, not column.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I will modify the row and column.

Comment: What @TomSharpe said, I'm looking to exclude the first (and last) column with a value for each row, not the first row, but that's a simple correction. Also:

If I expand the set it doesn't seem to add up (for example, I added another 'Blue' to column E, and it adds it to the sum), as the actual data-set may expand infinitely in both directions, and I need to have the formula be able to accommodate an ever-changing range. :(

It's worth noting as well, the rows all wont shrink in size, so the first row can't be used as a reference for maximum row length containing values.

Comment: @newacc2240 Your formula works assuming the data-set's max column range is determined by the first row (being the longest in the example). I've edited my question's data set to provide a more complex example, since your formula doesn't work when I apply it to a broader range with more variance.

Comment: No, I'm **not** assuming the data-set's max column range is determined by the first row. You have to **adjust** the formula to fit your data-set since I don't know the size of your actual data. I have no idea what do you mean by _doesn't work_. An error? An unexpected answer? Or what? I've tested the new example, it returns 2 for `Blue`, 2 for `Red`, and 0 for `Light blue`. Seems nothing wrong.

Comment: @newacc2240 The size of the data-set being indeterminable is part of the issue. The real-world data set could span any number of rows or columns. I'm not trying to suggest you're wrong, just that it doesn't appear to work with other data-sets.

Here's a workbook with a broader example using the same formula you provided: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IH3HD1igTAgcGOgLQUSkXxWDjkfvUSs-1a_gR-Vn0Dg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't have the permission of your document. And, **STOP saying doesn't work**. Tell me what the result is. Otherwise I have no clue to tell why you can't get the expected result.

Comment: @newacc2240 I don't know why you're becoming so angry, I attempted to show you what the result was with that link. Nobody's attacking you or your approach. If you can provide me an email I can give you access to the document to show you the issue.

Comment: I'm not angry but a little upset. Like I said, not just telling **doesn't work**, state the problem you're facing more clearly with more details. There are too many possibilities. You said that you post the result with that link and wishing me to provide my email. However actually I've asked the permission immediately when I found that I can't access the file. Furthermore, you can simply set the accessibility of the file to **everyone knows the link can read**. If so, everyone in stackoverflow can help you solve the problem together.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do it like this?

[image]

The bottom formula for column A is:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A6,"Blue")
```

That will count any "Blue" occurrences in the A2:A6 range. You can just copy that formula to the rest of the columns. Notice that I excluded the topmost (A1:D1) & bottommost (A7:D7) part for each column as per your instruction to avoid it.

If you want to count the occurrences all at once, you can do it like so:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:E6,"Blue")
```